# zombie tab in firefox while running selenium based test

Tags: firefox, selenium

We load a web page with excessive JS and Google maps API in firefox.

We do get an HTTP status 200, but the page does not load fully.

This happens sporadically.

The tab itself does have that turning bit on top which claims its not done yet.

The test simply waits until it magically finished loading.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: it pauses the test for a long time. instead of either refreshing the page, or giving some kind of error, it could stay like that for 20 minutes at a time.